# Centralizar números de páginação

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho a seguinte paginação: **< 1 2 3 4 >**.
Perfeito, o que acontece, é que essa paginação está no meio da página. 
Eu consigo centralizar a `div` que irá conter esses números, mas e como fazer para centralizar os números?
Lembrando que esses números são dinâmicos, usei esses 4 só como exemplo, e ainda tem as flechas **<** e **>**, que vai para **última** e **primeira** página. Existe algum plugin, ou alguma coisa que eu possa fazer apenas com CSS ou terei que efetuar cálculos com Jquery?

Ainda não montem a estrutura para isso.

```html
<ul>
    <li><</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>></li>
</ul>
```

Lembrando que os números **1 2 3 4** são exemplo, pode ter apenas 1, 2, 3, 4 e assim por diante.

Comment: Depende de como está o HTML disso. Inclua o código na pergunta.

Comment: Ja tentou usar `ul li{display:inline}` ? ou nao é isso que precisa?

Comment: @AntonyAlkmim não é isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```css
div.paginacao{float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center}
div.paginacao > div.list{display:inline-block}
div.paginacao ul{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: auto;}
div.paginacao ul > li{cursor: pointer; padding:2px; margin: 2px; float: left; border: 1px solid #ccc; width:20px; text-align: center}
div.paginacao ul > li:hover{background-color: #efefef;}
```

```html
<div class="paginacao">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>◄</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>►</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

## UPDATE

Comment: ótimo exemplo, mas como eu terei uma `li` que poderá ter menos de 4 itens, não serviu para mim, pois se tiver menos que 4 ele não centraliza corretamente

Comment: @FelipeStoker, fiz algumas alterações no exemplo. Acredito que agora atenda à sua necessidade.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, nunca consegui fazer isso só com CSS, sempre tive que usar Jquery :)

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo de como normalmente eu faço.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="pagination">
        <span>Página x de x</span>
        <span class="current">1</span>
        <a href='#' class="inactive">2</a>
        <a href='#' class="inactive">3</a>
        <a href='#' class="inactive">4</a>
        <a href="#">Próxima &rsaquo;</a>
        <a href='#'>Última &raquo;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pagination {
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
}

.pagination span, .pagination a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
    padding:6px 9px 5px 9px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ddd;
    background: #222;
}

.pagination .current{
    padding:6px 9px 5px 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #0950E8;
}
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fricks/b0uqfee9/)

Espero que seja útil.